# Renaming files with map function

Tags: python, dictionary, rename

I want to rename a list of files without using a `for` loop.

It is possible by using the `map` function like this:

```
import os

list( map( (lambda x: os.rename(x, x + "foo")), filelist ) )
```

...but it's not convenient: the returned `map` object needs to be "activated" by the `list` function.

So I'm looking for a kind of `map` procedure that would do the same, without shenanigans.

Comment: use a list comprehension instead.. wait...do a loop

Comment: It's generally considered a bad practice to use `map` or list comprehensions just for side effects - see for instance this question and its various answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects - you don't say _why_ you want to avoid a for loop, which would be the usual idiom.